Bot allow reaction Y only if reaction X has been added
    if user ==  and str(reaction.emoji) == "\U0001F5BC\U0000FE0F":
        channel = client.get_channel(1245390045859549285) #-reward-container
# Filter out mention at the start
        mention_regex = re.compile(r"^<@&(\d+)> ")
        filtered_content = mention_regex.sub("", reaction.message.content, 1)
        print(filtered_content)
        message = await channel.send(f"{filtered_content} by {reaction.message.author.mention}")
        await message.add_reaction("\U0001F5BC\U0000FE0F")

Trying to find a way to prevent people from adding this reaction before adding \U00002620\U0000fe0f first. I came up with this:
elif reaction.emoji == '\U0001F5BC\U0000FE0F':
  skull_reaction = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.reactions, emoji='\U00002620\U0000fe0f')
  is_skull_user = False
  async for skull_user in skull_reaction.users():
      if skull_user == user:
          is_skull_user = True
          break
  if not is_skull_user:
      await reaction.remove(user)

But that doesn't really work - Bot still adds its own message and when someone adds later on '\U00002620\U0000fe0f' nothing happens. Can someone help me with this?
Ive tried putting the 2nd part into the code but it doesn't do what I want - reaction is being removed but bot still adds reaction and then nothing happens

I have fixed this issue myself. Instead of making async for skull_user in skull_reaction_users() I've made variable for "if no skull_reaction". It looks like this:
 if user == reaction.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "\U0001F5BC\U0000FE0F":
    channel = client.get_channel(1245390045859549285) #-reward-container
    picture_reaction = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.reactions, emoji='\U0001F5BC\U0000FE0F')
    skull_reaction = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.reactions, emoji='\U00002620\U0000fe0f')
    print("2")

    if not skull_reaction:
        print("3")
        await picture_reaction.remove(user)
        return

Then the rest of the code.

I'm not familiar with discord py, but it seems like the emoji class can't be compared to a string, try adding an str like you did previously, ie elif str(reaction.emoji) == '\U0001F5BC\U0000FE0F':.
Hopefully that can fix our issue.
Also, according to the doc, the last part can be simplified into :
elif str(reaction.emoji) == '\U0001F5BC\U0000FE0F':
    skull_reaction = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.reactions, emoji='\U00002620\U0000fe0f')
    
    # Flatten the async iterator into a list
    users = [user async for user in skull_reaction.users()]
    
    # Check if the user is in the list of users who reacted
    if user not in users:
        await reaction.remove(user)

Hope that helps !

Nope, still getting same issue. Bot is still adding reaction and nothing happens after that.
https://codeshare.io/9brpwX full code if needed - working line 234
